# Claims based Authentication with JAVA based STS?

Tags: wif, authentication, claims

We have a java based STS service .We would like to use this STS for claims based authentication provided by WIF . Can someone provide some insight into how this can be acheieved ? All the examples I have come across use C# based STS and C# based RP . In my case the RP can be C# but the STS has to be in Java .Specifically,I would be interested in knowing how SAML requested is passed to the STS and the format of claims passed backed to the RP .

Thanks,
Somnath

Answer (score 1):

It depends what protocols your Java STS supports for requesting tokens.

In principle, if your Java STS implements the token request protocols from public standards WS-Trust & WS-Federation, and issues SAML 1.1 or SAML 2.0 tokens, a C# RP using WIF should be able to interoperate with it.

However, if your STS depends on some other request protocol such as SAML 2.0p then WIF doesn't currently support this directly. I believe ADFS does, however, and so there may well be a solution using ADFS as an intermediate STS federating with your Java-based STS in this case.